# how to give 30 second song preview from itunes in my own app

Tags: html, itunes

I'm implementing a web application for creating music playlists and I load song metadata from itunes. Now I want to give a 30 second song preview through my site. 
Can anyone tell me is this possible without registering with itunes affliate program?